# Friendly ID not updating slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

Using Rails 5 with Friendly ID 5.1.0

Trying to understand how to update the slug when a `Post` title is changed.

In the Friendly ID documentation it says you have to update the slug to `nil` before you can save your updated slug.

Example

```
post = Post.first
post.title # "My first post"
post.slug = "my-first=post"
post.title = "My newer first post"
post.save!
post.slug # "my-first=post"

# Setting to nil first
post.slug = nil
post.title = "My newer first post"
post.save!
post.slug # "my-newer-first-post"
```

In my Post model I have set `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` in hopes it will update the slug without manually setting the slug to `nil` from the console or a web form.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: post
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string           default(""), not null
#  body       :text             default(""), not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  slug       :string
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_posts_on_slug  (slug) UNIQUE
#

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :history

  private

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      title_changed? || super
    end
end
```

Is it the job of the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` method to update the slug if it's defined in your model?

Thanks again.

Comment: can you move to the latest version of friendly_id?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Using 5.1.0 latest.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this method in your model:

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
 title_changed?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, you should change the private method to:

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  slug.blank? || title_changed?
end
```

For reference https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/b6b6c004890ae3558a8ee19cc004a1456d9d0fff/lib/friendly_id/initializer.rb#L78